# Python efficient way to compare list item with partial item from other list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
link_ids = ['111','222','333']
filenames = ['111-foo.txt','111-bar.txt','222.txt']
```

I want to do two things.  First, find the filenames that match the Link IDs.  Second, create a list of the Link IDs that don't have matching files.

Its very simple, but it is doing my head in!  This clearly doesn't do what its supposed to, but its the best I can come up with:

```
missing = []
for i in link_ids:
    for f in filenames:
        if i in f:
            print 'match found'
        else:
            missing.append(i)
```

Please help if you can!

Comment: You probably want to use a string's  `.startswith()` method for matching.

Comment: Thanks Kimvais but the method of matching I use works fine.  It is the iteration I am struggling with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) is a good fit for this problem.
It gives you named-attributes without the additional overhead associated with a (non-optimised) class.

```
import collections, os

link_ids = ['111','222','333']
filenames = ['111-foo.txt','111-bar.txt','222.txt']
File = collections.namedtuple("File", "fname fext") # named-tuple set-up

files = {File(*os.path.splitext(f)) for f in filenames}
# -> set([File(fname='222', fext='.txt'), 
#         File(fname='111-bar', fext='.txt'), 
#         File(fname='111-foo', fext='.txt')])
```

"First, find the filenames that match the Link IDs.":

```
matched = [f for f in files if f.fname in link_ids]
# -> [File(fname='222', fext='.txt')]
```

"Second, create a list of the Link IDs that don't have matching files.":

```
unmatched = [l for l in link_ids if l not in {getattr(f,'fname') for f in files}]
# -> ['111', '333']
```

In a comment you mention wanting the full filename after matching.
For that you can do:

```
matched_filenames = [f.fname + f.fext for f in matched]
# -> ['222.txt']
```

Answer (score 1):

*I'm just starting to learn python, but I'll give it a shot...*

Maybe you could use the `set` facilities ?

```
>>> file_set = {i[:-4] for i in filenames}
>>> matched_links = set(link_ids) & file_set
>>> unmatched_links = set(link_ids) - file_set
```

Comment: is there a way to do this whilst preserving (or recovering) the full filename?

Answer (score 0):

First make a list of all the filename IDs but without the '.txt' extension:

```
>>> link_ids = ['111','222','333']
>>> filenames = ['111.txt','222.txt']
>>> filename_ids = [i[:-4] for i in filenames]
>>> filename_ids
['111', '222']
```

Then you can create two lists: IDs that match and IDs that don't match:

```
>>> match_ids = [i for i in link_ids if i in filename_ids]
>>> match_ids
['111', '222']
>>> not_match_ids = [i for i in link_ids if i not in filename_ids]
>>> not_match_ids
['333']
```

Comment: Oops, sorry.  I didn't explain I need the full filenames and I can't assume the extension.  I have edited my example code to suit.

Comment: This does not work for the OP data, I guess that's why you used different filesnames ...

Answer (score 0):

```
link_ids = ['111','222','333']
filenames = ['111-foo.txt','111-bar.txt','222.txt']

missing = []
found = []
for i in link_ids:
    for f in filenames:
        if i in f:
            print 'match found'
            found.append(i)

missing = list(set(link_ids) - set(found))
print 'Missing link ids: ', missing
```

**Output:**

```
match found
match found
match found
Missing link ids:  ['333']
```